# Mutli-line AWK output to array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, nmap

I am having some issues with a script that I am writing.
Basically I want to retrieve a list of active IP address and add them into an array.
But unfortunately after looking everywhere I haven't quite found a solution.

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ipnet="192.168.0.0/24"
tail /proc/uptime | grep -o '^\S*'
Iparray=($(nmap -n -sn $ipnet -oG - | awk '/Up$/{print $2}'))
echo $Iparray[3]
echo "Active IPs:"
for i in "${Iparray[@]}"
do
    :
    echo $Iparray[$i]
done
```

But instead of the expected output being a list of IP's, I get this:

```
16977.41
192.168.0.1[3]
Active IPs:
192.168.0.1[192.168.0.1]
192.168.0.1[192.168.0.2]
192.168.0.1[192.168.0.3]
192.168.0.1[192.168.0.4]
...
192.168.0.1[192.168.0.254]
```

Not really quite sure what is happening... 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very tiny issue:

The `${Iparray[@]}` is the list of the IP addresses, so you could:

```
for ip in ${Iparray[@]}; do
    echo $ip
done
```

OR

If you really want to use indexes:

```
for  (( i=0; i<${#Iparray[@]}; i++ )) ; do 
      echo ${Iparray[$i]}
done
```